# How do I create a 2 digit random number with RNGCryptoServiceProvider class?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a random number but it has a certain amount of digits that I can't reduce. How can I actually get only a 2 digit random number with this secure method?

```
    {   Console.WriteLine("{0}",GetRandom());Console.ReadLine();

    }
    private static int GetRandom()
    {

        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        {
             byte[] randomNumber = new byte[4];
             rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
             int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(randomNumber,0);
             return value;
```

Comment: Do you mean two digit decimal (0 - 99) or two digit hex (0 - 255)?

Comment: That's dangerous, you can't use the obvious % operator due to unequal distribution.  Take 7 bits of the rng (& 0x7f).  If it is less than 100 then its good, if not then repeat.

Comment: two digit decimal I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the % known as [modulo operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx). It's unsual generate a range of PRNG with `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` but it has a smaller bias then `System.Random`.
Your code should look like this:

```
private static int GetRandom(int min, max) {
using(System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
             byte[] randomNumber = new byte[4];
             rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
             int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(randomNumber,0);
             return Math.Abs(value%max+min);
        }
}
```

I've used `Math.Abs` so you will get only positive number but you can remove it.